# Flutter: remove non-consumable purchase with in_app_purchase package for testing

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I am testing [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) package. No problems when using consumable subscriptions, but for non-consumable (buy once) I cannot find a way to remove it for testing purpose.

I see in the InAppPurchaseConnection class there is consumePurchase(PurchaseDetails purchase) function, but it doesn't work for non-consumable.

Is currently possible to remove a purchase?

Thanks for your time!

**UPDATE:**

```
adb shell pm clear com.android.vending
```

I used this shell command to remove the test purchase, don't know if it removes also the real one so take care!

Answer (score 0):

For android you may try Play Console -> Order management -> View order details -> check Remove Entitlement -> press Refund